# I can't get the value of a query outside the loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop

I'm using PHP and I do a mysql query and I save the result of this query in an array. Then, I use a loop and into the loop i do another mysql query using the values of the array in the where clause. It's right but if I try to get the result of the query outside the loop I can't.
Here an example code

```
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT code FROM referee");
$i=0;
$arcode=array();
while($row=$result->fetch_array()){ 
    $arcode[$i]=$row["code"];
    $i++;
}
for($j=0;$j<sizeof($arcode);$j++){
    $result2=$mysqli->query("SELECT code, time FROM match where referee_code IN ($arcode[$j])");
}

/*Here I can't get the result values*/
$matcode=array();
$hour=array();
$k=0;
while($row2=$result2->fetch_array()){
     $matcode[$k]=$row2["code"];
     $hour[$k]=$row2["time"];
}
```

If I put all in the same loop I get the result repeated (This code is one example of all my code but the idea is the same in the rest).

Comment: You could use a single query: `SELECT code, time FROM match WHERE referee_code IN (SELECT code FROM referee)`

Comment: Thaks I will use it in all my querys if it's work at all

Comment: These days, joins are preferable to sub-selects: `SELECT referee.code, \`match\`.time FROM referee JOIN \`match\` ON referee.code = \`match\`.referee_code`. In general, joins allow for better optimization, as well as making better use of the relational model.

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the result set values into `$result2`.

The correct method would be something like:

```
$matcode = array();
$hour = array();
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT code, 
                                 time 
                            FROM `match` 
                           WHERE referee_code IN (SELECT code 
                                                    FROM referee)");
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array())
{
    $matcode[] = $row2["code"];
    $hour[] = $row2["time"];
}
```

You may change the index values according to the way you want the array to look like.

Also `match` is a reserved word. So you would have to enclose it in backticks.

Comment: If I do it the result is repeated at the end of all the querys.

Comment: @temerariomalaga Give me a moment, I'll set it right.

Comment: There is no need for 2 loops check my comment on his question or injecting an array.

Comment: @temerariomalaga Could you try now?

Comment: @Prix Oops, didn't see your comment there. Will amend.

Comment: @temerariomalaga Don't forget to use backticks `` around match since it's a reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print complete data then try this :

```
$matcode = array();
$hour = array();
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT code, 
                                 time 
                            FROM `match` 
                           WHERE referee_code IN (SELECT code 
                                                    FROM referee)");
$completeData=array();
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array())
{
    $completeData[] = $row2;
}
print_r($completeData);
```

Don forget to accept answer if it helps :)